# unrecognized -a option `ck_size'

Tags: gcc, openmp, gfortran

I am using GCC ver-4.6.4 (both in Mac and Linux Mint 15) to compile a code I do for research.

The command I am using is :

```
gfortran -O2 -fopenmp -Wl,-stack_size,1000000 <...Lots of files...> -o a.out
```

, where I omit the actual file names.

This code compiles OK in Mac, however I get the following error in Mint:

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized -a option `ck_size'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

In Mint, this will compile if I do not use any flags at all, therefore this problem is related to OpenMP.

However, I do need OpenMP and do not understand what it says in the error, because I do not have 'ck_size'. BTW, deleting -O2 doesn't help.

Comment: Mind that the maximum stack size for the main thread on OS X is 64 MB. Other OpenMP threads could have very large stacks but the main thread cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not related to OpenMP, it is related to your different OS's.

`-stack_size` is specific to Macintosh and refers to the maximal size of arrays on the stack. Linux changes the stack size via the terminal command `ulimit` (to check your Mint settings type, `ulimit -a` to see everything, the stack size can be seen with `ulimit -s`, see the [ulimit man page](http://www.ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) for more information).

Thus, you need to scrap that whole `-stack_size,100000` portion from your compiler flag, it means nothing in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You passed `-Wl,-stack_size,1000000` to gfortran, which is passing on the option "-stack_size 1000000" to the linker ld. It is interpreting "st" as single letter options "-s" and "-t", then reading the next letter as an option "-a", and the rest of the word ("ck_size") as its parameter.

I could find no reference to a `-stack_size` option for `ld`. It looks like the option is `--stack`, so you need to put something like `-Wl,--stack,1000000` instead.

Comment: `-Wl,--stack,1000000` does not work, it is still unrecognized; My original code `-Wl,-stack_size,1000000` is from Apple's suggestion [Customizing Process Stack Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1419/_index.html), and works on mac only I think.